# XML Parsing in python(xml.etree.ElementTree)

Tags: python, xml

I am using **import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET** for parsing xml file in python

I tried:

```
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
   tree = ET.parse('pyxml.xml')
   self.root = tree.getroot()
   name=root[0][0].text
   username=root[0][1].text
   password=root[0][2].text
   host=root[0][3].text
   port=root[0][4].text
```

pyxml.xml:

```
<data>
    <database>
        <name>qwe</name>
        <username>postgres</username>
        <password>1234</password>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <port>5432</port>
    </database>
</data>
```

But I want XML file like:

```
<data>
<database name="abc"  username="xyz" password="dummy" host="localhost" port="5432"/>
</data>
```

If I do like this,root[0][0].text is not working.Can anyone tell how to access it?

Comment: I might suggest adding the title by something like "xml flatten" or "xml child to attribute" so that future users may benefit from your question. (Looking forward to an answer, too)

Comment: yeah sure.I'll change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('/Users/a-8525/Documents/tmp/pyxml.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

database = root.find('database')
attribute = database.attrib

name = attribute['name']
username = attribute['username']
password =attribute['password']
host = attribute['host']
port = attribute['port']
```

Comment: I want to parse from XML file.I don't want to generate XML file

Comment: `child.tag, child.text` this way you can get the tag name and tag value which you need.

Comment: @Ramya you meant to say ,you want to parse the XML content `<data>
<database name="abc"  username="xyz" password="dummy" host="localhost" port="5432"/>
</data>` ??

Comment: yeah.I want to do like that.Can you please help me this